# Magento - catalogrule on attribute not working

Tags: magento

we have here some problems with our Magento system.

*First the background*:

We have some products where we have boxes. Now we have created at startup an attribute **packaging_size** this attribute is a "dropdown" with some values like 10, 20, 25, 50 and so on.

Now we want to give 3% to all articles with attribute "packaging_size" and value 20 for example. So I configured the condition to "packaging_size is 20" **but nothing happen** in the shopping cart and on the detail view.

> Is it possible to set a rule on an attribute? or is it not possible?

How can I find the place where the price is calculated perhaps I can start and debug. The product is a **configurable product** linked to under products with the attribute.

I hope somebody can help me. I have searched a lot in the source code bit i have found not so much.

Its not working in Magento **1.5.0.1** and **1.6.0.0**

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to generally relate to programming or software development in some way, within the scope defined in the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: @Anton S: I know. I need a line where i can start searching to debug. But when its not possible i cannot debug it.

Comment: if you know that then please redefine your question and ask what you mean not what you think others would think you mean :) and thats before you get down-voted and closed as currently this is not a question that fits here

Comment: i put another question on bottom i search now for days if its possible -.- but its not working really annoying. You can configure it but nothing happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rules were always a mess in Magento, sometimes they work, some they don't, and this is on a daily basis...

I still have big problems in 1.5, but I thought they had fixed all with the new 1.6, but it seams, for your question, that they don't, they keep adding functionality that they think we might want and forget the old stuff that we need and it's broken... Even bought by eBay, they are doing the same...

**What you can do is**, first, verify that the cache is disabled, then clean the physical cache (delete all under `/var/cache/`)

If that doesn't do the trick, open `/app/code/core/Mage/Rule/Model/Rule.php` and try to debug it... **it will be messy**, and if you are asking for a simple *where can I debug this*, I can assure you that you're not the best candidate to debug Mage :)

Comment: thanks its really angry this problem... i have looked in the core on many places and i have found some lines where i have the right output. I know Mage debug is not really funny ^^ and i have normaly not the time @work to debug Mage... this is the main problem. I will to to the Rule.php i wil test your solution and give a feedback.